# How to convert handlebars partial parameters to pug/jade?

Tags: handlebars.js, pug

Small but difficult question for me. How to convert this code to pug? I'm currently learning web programming and writing my first project in pug.

```
{{#each people}}
   {{> myPartial prefix=../prefix firstname=firstname lastname=lastname}}.
{{/each}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pug doesn't have partials, but it does have [mixins](https://pugjs.org/language/mixins.html), which are a similar concept that allow you to reuse and pass parameters to blocks of code.

Assuming you've rewritten `myPartial` as a valid mixin called `myMixin`, and assuming `people` is an array of objects with properties `firstname` and `lastname`, you could write this in Pug as:

```
each person in people
  +myMixin(person.firstname, person.lastname)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. But what about the this keyword? I have read the documentation for both template engines several times, but I still hit the wall. Example: {{>myPartial prefix=this someId=../some._id}}

Comment: I'm not sure what `prefix` does in Handlebars.

Comment: I think it's a local variable. I took an example from here https://handlebarsjs.com/guide/partials.html#basic-partials